# Getting object property through object id

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm a bit new to JS, so please be descriptive.

I have two instances of an object, and I need to get value of a property of one instance into the other one. As I know JS lacks support of in-memory object ids (not DOM ids), so I have to create such a property. Currently I'm using recursion to create multiple objects, but it's just for the test.

```
function MyObject(parentID, parentProperty) {
    this.id = parentID + 1
    this.myProperty = parentProperty + 1

    switch(this.id){
        case 5:
        break;

        default:
        new MyObject(this.id, this.myProperty)
    } 
}
var myObject = new MyObject(1, 1);
```

So now I have 4 objects. How do I get myProperty value of object with, for example, id = 3?

Comment: The objects that you're creating within the constructor aren't stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to retrive an object with, say, a property value, you need to store them in an Array or Object hash. I recommend using a factory method to construct your objects. When you construct the objects in the factory method also store those object references in a Hash/Array keyed by their property values you want to search for at a later point in time.

For example,

```
(function(globalScope) {
    var objectCache = [],
        ObjectFactory;

    globalScope.ObjectFactory = ObjectFactory = {
        create : function(parentID, parentProperty) {
            var newObj = new function() {
                this.id = parentID + 1
                this.myProperty = parentProperty + 1                 
            };
            objectCache.push(newObj);
            return newObj;
        },
        findObjectById : function(parentId) {
            //iterate through objectCache and find your object and returna
        }
    };  
})(this);
```

To store objects in a Object hash (instead of an Array)

```
var objHashCache = {};
var obj = new Object();
objHashCache[obj.id] = obj;
```

when you want to retrive the object by its ID, you can use

```
return objHashCache[idToLookFor]
```

Comment: So I cannot store a direct link to an object, and using that link retrieve needed properties' values? Iteration wouldn't be very good for performance, wouldn't it?

Comment: You can store a direct link (the object reference itself) to the Object in an Array and iterate through it. If you are going to do more querying than inserting/deleting, you could use a object hash ({}) and store the references in the object hash. See my answer edit for a pseudo code.

Comment: I will check out this solution tonight, thnx. Do I understand correctly that I will have to use something like | return objHashCache[3].myProperty() |?

Comment: It worked, but I cannot reach another object from inside current object constructor: | this.myProperty = objHashCache[this.id - 1].myProperty + 1 | throws an error.
I'm currently creating objects in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would store a static map of objects on the `MyObject` function itself, with the key being the `id`. Populate that map in the constructor, and then you have a map of all the instances of the object created.

In your example:

```
function MyObject(parentID, parentProperty) {
    this.id = parentID + 1;
    this.myProperty = parentProperty + 1;
    MyObject.instances = MyObject.instances || {};
    MyObject.instances[this.id] = this;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var myObject = new MyObject(i, i);
}
var thirdObject = MyObject.instances[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to iterate through all of your object and find your object with a condition.

If you know linq and that better fits to your needs you could use linq (http://linqjs.codeplex.com)

(I’m from mobile and I'll fix my answer's formating  when I get front of a pc )